Сборка PortAudio в Microsoft Visual Studio C1083
Хочу собрать PortAudio, делаю всё по этому руководству: https://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html


From the Build menu click Build -> Build solution. For 32-bit compilations, the dll file created by this process (portaudio_x86.dll) can be found in the directory build\msvc\Win32\Release. For 64-bit compilations, the dll file is called portaudio_x64.dll, and is found in the directory build\msvc\x64\Release.


На 10 этапе в консоли появляются 4 ошибки:

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\host\pc\asiolist.cpp': No such file or directory  portaudio   C:\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\host\pc\asiolist.cpp    1


Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\host\asiodrivers.cpp': No such file or directory  portaudio   C:\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\host\asiodrivers.cpp    1


Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\common\asio.cpp': No such file or directory   portaudio   C:\src\hostapi\asio\ASIOSDK\common\asio.cpp 1


Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'asiosys.h': No such file or directory    portaudio   C:\Users\gosha\source\repos\SoundPad\SoundPad\portaudio-master\portaudio-master\src\hostapi\asio\pa_asio.cpp    116

Нигде не нашёл решения этой проблемы.
Возможно плохо искал...
Если нужна будет более подробная информация — пишите.
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Всё, я решил.
Просто забилдил через Cmake
